# R tidyverse move certain rows to top or arrange by custom rules

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've tried different ways and searched for similar questions but no good luck.

I'd like to arrange and distinct my df in with a customized rule, where I keep only one row per group with the smallest `val`. But when 1 is availabile in `val` for example, I'd like to keep 1 instead of the smallest value.

`val` is the value column and `ID` is the ID column:

```
x = data.frame(ID=c("a", "a", 
                    "b", "b", 
                    "c", "c", 
                    "d", "d"),
               val=c(1, 2, 
                     0.5, 2,
                     1, 0.5,
                     5, 20))
```

`x` looks like:

```
  ID  val
1  a  1.0
2  a  2.0
3  b  0.5
4  b  2.0
5  c  1.0
6  c  0.5
7  d  5.0
8  d 20.0
```

I tried something like:

```
x %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(val) %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = T) %>% arrange(ID)
```

and it gives me:

```
  ID      val
1 a       1  
2 b       0.5
3 c       0.5
4 d       5
```

Tried `slice_min`:

```
x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_min(order_by = tibble(val != 1, val), n = 1, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

and it gives me:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  ID      val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 c         1
3 d         5
Warning messages:
1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
2: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
3: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
4: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

Desired output:

```
  ID      val
1 a       1  
2 b       0.5
3 c       1
4 d       5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can arrange by `val != 1` and `val` and use `slice_head()` on your grouped data.

```
x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(val != 1, val) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  ID      val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a       1  
2 b       0.5
3 c       1  
4 d       5
```

Or using the development version of `dplyr` you can use `slice_min()` and make use of the `order_by` argument which can take multiple variables via `tibble()`:

```
x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_min(order_by = tibble(val != 1, val), n = 1, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Hi Ritchie, thanks for the quick response. I didn't know about slice_min(). I got a 3*2 tibble where row with ID b is gone with slice_min(). Also a warning message saying In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames. Any thoughts?

Comment: Edited. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I was using the development version of dplyr which supports multiple variables to order by via using a tibble. The current version supports only a single variable.  Have added an alternative approach.

Comment: didn't know that I could add val!=1 in arrange. Thanks a lot Ritchie!